# How to catch/expect the error: F tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_event_mgr.cc:273] Unexpected Event status: 1

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

**TF version 1.x and 2.x.**

Is there a way to catch this error with `try-expect` in `python`?

> F tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_event_mgr.cc:273] Unexpected
> Event status: 1

Comment: wrap function that throws the error in try: function() except: pass

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/45900